# How to use php header in Tidesdk

Tags: php, header, tidesdk, force-download

I am trying to generate the force download excel file in my Tidesdk app.So i am trying the following code to work, but it is not working properly.So guys please help me to find out the solution.

```
<?php
    header ("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=sheet.xls" );
    echo 'First Name' . "\t" . 'Last Name' . "\t" . 'Phone' . "\n";
    echo 'Maddy' . "\t" . 'Shan' . "\t" . '555-4445' . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: How does the application behave if you do not set the headers? Are the lines displayed then?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
    <?php
```

and

```
    ?>
```

and you should be good to go !

Comment: Hi Mital, Here is my code still it showing the data, but force download is not working.Can you please check
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/php">
    header("Content-type: application/excel");
 header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=sheet.xls" );
 echo 'First Name' . "\t" . 'Last Name' . "\t" . 'Phone' . "\n";
 echo 'Maddy' . "\t" . 'Shan' . "\t" . '555-4445' . "\n";
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: In my app i am providing an option to export the data. Is there any other alternate option for this issue?